How to Hide bundle.js or source code Files of React webistes from Users?
I have a React-based website with a Django backend, deployed using Kubernetes and nginx. To manage secrets, I've utilized a .env file, storing sensitive information as process.env.var_name. However, after deployment, inspecting the website reveals the entire source code, including the secrets with their actual values, instead of process.env.var_name.
I've attempted solutions such as setting "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false" in .env and the build script of package.json, which successfully hide the source files of the website but not the bundle.js files under sourceTab/static/js.
I'm seeking advice on how to effectively secure my secrets and conceal the source code from clients.
Requirements:
Ensure that sensitive information stored in the .env file is not exposed in the source code visible to clients.
Conceal the source code files, including bundle.js, from being accessible through inspection or other means.
Minimize any performance impact or disruption to the existing deployment setup.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is not possible to hide the (client side) Javascript code from the user.
The code runs inside the browser, so it must necessarily be downloaded to the client, and thus can be inspected in one way or another.
You can make the code hard to read, but you can not hide it.
When people talk about secrets stored in .env files, they use these secrets only in server side code, not in client side code.
If you need to access some secured API, then you can create some kind of server side middleware, which has all necessary rights and secrets (and whose code is not visible from the client), and make publicly visible requests only from the browser to that middleware, and secret requests only from that middleware to the secured API.

How to secure our secrets,Assume i am sending my secrets to frontend using api,then people can inspect and see the response under network section.
If you say,encrypt the secrets at backend and send to frontend,then we need write the encryption logic in the frontend which is again can read by users,so they can use same logic and decrypt.
If we send all secrets under jwt token,it also can be decoded using a lot of free tools online.

You should never expose "secrets" to the frontend (like API keys). - For a solution it depends on your use case, e.g. what exactly you mean by "secrets". - If you need to pass "secret" data between backend and frontend, you need to implement some kind of login first, which creates "temporary secrets", which are also visible by the frontend, but that's ok, because they are only for the current session (or "usage"). E.g. OAuth.

Sorry to say this,i did not understand your solution.lets say,i hit an api called "/getKeys" whose response is {googleMapkey:"xxxyyyzzz"}
which i am getting from the backend and i intended to keep the secret key value in the map component like 

Now any one can inspect api call in network tab and can see the key value.
If i send by encoding in backend,in the frontend i have to write decoding logic since i can not pass the same value to map which can not understand,then user knows the logic of decoding,if i send the key in jwt,then also user can decode the jwt using free online tools,so what is the best approach we can follow to secure secrets in react

Yes, that is correct, the user can inspect everything that is received by the browser in the network tab. It is simply not possible to avoid that. Therefore you have to write the app so that it doesn't need a secret in the frontend, generally. - Specifically, I don't know the Google Maps API, but I found "Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs", I don't know if that helps. I suggest to ask a new specific question about how to secure the Google Maps API.

The basic idea is that the user enters credentials (e.g. user name and password), then some kind of temporary access token is generated and sent to the frontend. That access token is used by the frontend, validated on the server, and then the real secret key is used only by the server to access the secret API. The access token can also be inspected on the frontend, but that's ok, it can be invalidated / revoked whenever you want (expires after some time, valid for one session, valid only one time, ...). But it's a bit more complicated, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth.
